# What site do you specify when applying for key to google maps?

Tags: google-maps

I may be dim, but I really don't know what to answer when google asks me for a URL when asking for a key for google maps.

I mean, I'm on my laptop, with no internet dns entry developing the solution in visual studio, so what do i tell google? localhost? The domain name I know the site will end up on? my laptops name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key which will correspond to the name of the server in the URL. I've used both localhost and the name of the laptop on local network.

Change to a different key on the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I have always set up the API key to represent the sites future URL.  I have seen no issues with using the API key on localhost that was setup for domainname.com, but that may be related to the subset of the Google Map APIs that I utilize.  I would use your site's final URL when you set up the key for Google Maps.

Comment: name matters running local also.  I have keys made up for http://localhost and then one for my testing and production machines.
Ultimately wherever the map is going to be HOSTED from

Comment: What issues have you had, I have had none running local with a specific key?  What API functions were you using that resulted in the issues?